# Gremlin query works or not depending on the context

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

In a query (by the way written by stephen mallette in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002287/gremlin-cannot-go-back-to-a-previous-step-after-calling-fold-or-count)) the problem is that works in gremlify, but when I paste it in my project gives an incorrect output.

So I opened gremlify to write a data creation query to then paste it in the gremlin console so I can test it there, and I noticed it doesn't work in gremlify if it's executed after the data creation part of the query and it should work as far as I understand.

The query is this:

```
g.V().as('a').
  repeat(both().simplePath()).
    times(2).
  where(both().as('a')).
  path().
  map(unfold().limit(3).order().by(id).dedup().fold())
  dedup().
  group('m').
    by(limit(local,2)).
  group('m').
    by(tail(local,2)).
  group('m').
    by(union(limit(local,1),tail(local,1)).fold()).     
  cap('m').
  unfold().
  map(select(values).unfold().unfold().order().by(id).dedup().fold()).
  dedup().
  map(unfold().values('name').fold())
```

Here it works, output is correct:
https://gremlify.com/psiygozr559

Here it gives an incorrect output:
https://gremlify.com/mqw6ut0y1z
(same graph but created with a query)

Here it does not give any output at all:
https://gremlify.com/fzgmzdq1omq
(same than before with a change in line 1)

In my project also gives an incorrect output and I'm not executing anything weird before the query like in the gremlify projects above.

There is another query that does the same, I wrote it myself, is less efficient but works perfectly in all the same situations and in my project, see:

https://gremlify.com/zihygx0w8e

https://gremlify.com/xsc6q8dranj

In my project I'm connecting to gremlin server locally with with the default configuration untouched, using Node.js.

Something is happening here that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By extending the traversal you've extended the `Path`. Placing `addV('j')` at the front of the traversal adds something my original algorithm did not take into account:

```
gremlin> g.addV("j").sideEffect(V().drop()).sideEffect(
......1>     addV("user").property("name", "luana").as("luana")
......2>     .addV("user").property("name", "luisa").as("luisa")
......3>     .addV("user").property("name", "sabrina").as("sabrina")
......4>     .addV("user").property("name", "marcello").as("marcello")
......5>     .addV("user").property("name", "mario").as("mario")
......6>     .addV("user").property("name", "lidia").as("lidia")
......7>     
......7>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("luisa")
......8>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("sabrina")
......9>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("marcello")
.....10>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("mario")
.....11>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("lidia")
.....12>     
.....12>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("luisa")
.....13>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("marcello")
.....14>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("mario")
.....15>     
.....15>     .addE("friend").from("mario").to("luisa")
.....16>     .addE("friend").from("mario").to("marcello")
.....17>     ).V().as('a').
.....18>   repeat(both().simplePath()).
.....19>     times(2).
.....20>   where(both().as('a')).
.....21>   path().by(label)
==>[j,user,user,user]
==>[j,user,user,user]
==>[j,user,user,user]
==>[j,user,user,user]
...
==>[j,user,user,user]
```

You can account for that by naming the path you care about or otherwise limiting or filtering away that initial path element:

```
gremlin> g.addV("j").sideEffect(V().drop()).sideEffect(
......1>     addV("user").property("name", "luana").as("luana")
......2>     .addV("user").property("name", "luisa").as("luisa")
......3>     .addV("user").property("name", "sabrina").as("sabrina")
......4>     .addV("user").property("name", "marcello").as("marcello")
......5>     .addV("user").property("name", "mario").as("mario")
......6>     .addV("user").property("name", "lidia").as("lidia")
......7>     
......7>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("luisa")
......8>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("sabrina")
......9>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("marcello")
.....10>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("mario")
.....11>     .addE("friend").from("luana").to("lidia")
.....12>     
.....12>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("luisa")
.....13>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("marcello")
.....14>     .addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("mario")
.....15>     
.....15>     .addE("friend").from("mario").to("luisa")
.....16>     .addE("friend").from("mario").to("marcello")
.....17>     ).V().as('a').
.....18>   repeat(both().simplePath()).
.....19>     times(2).
.....20>   where(both().as('a')).
.....21>   path().from('a').
.....22>   map(unfold().limit(3).order().by(id).dedup().fold()).
.....23>   dedup().
.....24>   group('m').
.....25>     by(limit(local,2)).
.....26>   group('m').
.....27>     by(tail(local,2)).
.....28>   group('m').
.....29>     by(union(limit(local,1),tail(local,1)).fold()).     
.....30>   cap('m').
.....31>   unfold().
.....32>   map(select(values).unfold().unfold().order().by(id).dedup().fold()).
.....33>   dedup().
.....34>   map(unfold().values('name').fold())
==>[luana,luisa,sabrina,mario]
==>[luana,sabrina,marcello,mario]
==>[luana,luisa,sabrina,marcello,mario]
```

Note line 21 above where we simply add `path().from('a')` which says, start the path at the step label "a", and then the query starts working again.

Regarding your other example that doesn't use `sideEffect()` to add the sample graph data, note the output of `path()` when it follows `repeat()`:

```
gremlin> g.addV("j").sideEffect(V().drop()).
......1>   addV("user").property("name", "luana").as("luana").
......2>   addV("user").property("name", "luisa").as("luisa").
......3>   addV("user").property("name", "sabrina").as("sabrina").
......4>   addV("user").property("name", "marcello").as("marcello").
......5>   addV("user").property("name", "mario").as("mario").
......6>   addV("user").property("name", "lidia").as("lidia").
......7>     
......7>   addE("friend").from("luana").to("luisa").
......8>   addE("friend").from("luana").to("sabrina").
......9>   addE("friend").from("luana").to("marcello").
.....10>   addE("friend").from("luana").to("mario").
.....11>   addE("friend").from("luana").to("lidia").
.....12>     
.....12>   addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("luisa").
.....13>   addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("marcello").
.....14>   addE("friend").from("sabrina").to("mario").
.....15>     
.....15>   addE("friend").from("mario").to("luisa").
.....16>   addE("friend").from("mario").to("marcello").
.....17>   V().as('a').both().path()
==>[v[712],v[713],v[715],v[717],v[719],v[721],v[723],e[725][713-friend->715],e[726][713-friend->717],e[727][713-friend->719],e[728][713-friend->721],e[729][713-friend->723],e[730][717-friend->715],e[731][717-friend->719],e[732][717-friend->721],e[733][721-friend->715],e[734][721-friend->719],v[721],v[715]]
==>[v[712],v[713],v[715],v[717],v[719],v[721],v[723],e[725][713-friend->715],e[726][713-friend->717],e[727][713-friend->719],e[728][713-friend->721],e[729][713-friend->723],e[730][717-friend->715],e[731][717-friend->719],e[732][717-friend->721],e[733][721-friend->715],e[734][721-friend->719],v[721],v[719]]
...
==>[v[712],v[713],v[715],v[717],v[719],v[721],v[723],e[725][713-friend->715],e[726][713-friend->717],e[727][713-friend->719],e[728][713-friend->721],e[729][713-friend->723],e[730][717-friend->715],e[731][717-friend->719],e[732][717-friend->721],e[733][721-friend->715],e[734][721-friend->719],v[719],v[721]]
```

As you've added vertices/edges outside of the `sideEffect()` they are included in that output. Therefore, `simplePath()` immediately filters them away as soon as you try to traverse `V().as('a')`!

```
==>[v[712],v[713],v[715],v[717],v[719],v[721],v[723],e[725][713-friend->715],e[726][713-friend->717],e[727][713-friend->719],e[728][713-friend->721],e[729][713-friend->723],e[730][717-friend->715],e[731][717-friend->719],e[732][717-friend->721],e[733][721-friend->715],e[734][721-friend->719],v[721],v[715]]
```

See how `v[721]` appears twice - once for `addV()` and once for `V()`. `simplePath()` sees that you traversed that vertex and returned to it.

My approach to debugging this (as the answer was not immediately clear) was to first `profile()` the two traversals and compare the counts of the like sections. I noted where they started to differ which put me in the viscinity of where the problem started. From there I started executing the query up to those steps side-by-side until I noted the difference in output around the `Path`. You can learn a bit on how to pick apart and debug Gremlin queries [here](https://www.slideshare.net/StephenMallette/gremlins-anatomy-88713465).

Comment: There is still one of the issues I posted that doesn't get fixed by adding from('a'), this one: https://gremlify.com/uoqttm3rg5p I fixed it by removing simplePath(), because I noticed that after simplePath() nothing is returned. I don't know why that issue happens. Maybe you can give me some info about this.

Comment: by not side-effecting in those `addV()` and `addE()` calls you've placed more objects on the path. those newly added vertices will immediately show a cycle on the first `both()` and `simplePath()` filters them away. You can see the effect if you add this: `V().as('a').both().path()` after the last `addE()`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. As far as I understand, selecting all the vertices of the graph using V() is the same than having these vertices selected because I created them using addV(). Why simplePath() behaves in a different way depending on how the vertices got selected?

Comment: i've updated my answer with some explanation as to what i'd asked you to try out with `V().as('a').both().path()` - hopefully that makes sense now. the `Path` is more than just what you traversed over `V()` - it's the entire line of elements that Gremlin has traversed over including mutations, transformations, etc.

Comment: you were thinking of it right. `simplePath()` does filter the results of a step. the result of `path()` in my example includes all the vertices created by the `addV()` steps, so when you then traverse all vertices with `V()` you immediately create a cycle and `simplePath()` filters that particular path out. It will do that for ALL of the paths you traverse because there will always be the full list of every vertex in the graph created by `addV()` and then one of those vertices traversed from `V()`. Review the example some more and see that each `Path` object sees one vertex more than once.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks for your patience. I was confused because I thought ```g.V().V().simplePath()``` should then return no results but it does if there are more than 1 vertex. But I noticed ```g.V().V().V().simplePath()``` returns no results so I can now make a mental image of what is happening.